# Retention Policy issue in InfluxDB

Tags: influxdb

I've installed influxdb and created a bucket "test" via UI and I selected 1 hour when asked, "Delete data older than?"

[image]

As in the above image, I added a sample data row.

But when I checked after 1 hour, the row still exists.

Can someone explain to me why it's not still deleted?

The InfluxDB version I am using is 2.7.1